MySQL takes over 1 second to do many simple queries for table 2600+ rows
After detected my issues at Mysql process consumes High CPU & RAM even after reboot; I used slow query for my below info, please help me detect; seems over 1s to perform the simple queries are unacceptable?
Updates
Thank so much for all comments & replies. After adding 4 pairs of indexes that used frequently in WHERE & ORDER BY clauses: (display, submitday),  (cat_id, display),  (sub_id, display),  (url_rewrite, display); performance is better, very well but it still consumes more than 0.5s for tasks below:
# Query_time: 0.872697  Lock_time: 0.000096  Rows_sent: 10  Rows_examined: 2663
SELECT JS.id, JS.url_rewrite, JS.title_en 
FROM jsdata JS 
WHERE JS.display=1 AND JS.comments>0 
ORDER BY comments DESC LIMIT 0,10;


# Query_time: 0.643862  Lock_time: 0.000059  Rows_sent: 10  Rows_examined: 10
SELECT JS.id, JS.url_rewrite, JS.title_en 
FROM jsdata JS WHERE JS.display=1 AND JS.views>0 
ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 0,10;


# Query_time: 0.661634  Lock_time: 0.000050  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 2653
SELECT COUNT(*) AS sum FROM jsdata JS  WHERE JS.display=1 AND 1=1  AND cat_id = 10;

I think more than 0.3 (or 0.1) second to query above tasks is long for a table with 2000+ rows only, how & where I may improve more?
Thank you again

mysql version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.56-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

My table structure, has 2653 rows only
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jsdata` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url_rewrite` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `title_en` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `title_fr` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `title_vi` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `description_en` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `description_fr` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `description_vi` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `tags_en` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `tags_fr` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `tags_vi` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `submitday` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat_id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `sub_id` mediumint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `filename` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `views` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `comments` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `stores` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `marks` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `votes` float unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sents` mediumint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `image` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `code_files` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `code_css` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `code_js` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `code_html` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `display` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `filename` (`filename`),
  KEY `title_en` (`title_en`,`title_fr`,`title_vi`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=2843 ;

Slow queries
# Query_time: 1.029749  Lock_time: 0.000083  Rows_sent: 10  Rows_examined: 4883
SELECT JS.id, JS.url_rewrite, JS.title_en AS title, JS.description_en AS description, 
           JS.submitday, JS.image, JS.comments, JS.stores, JS.cat_id,  JS.sub_id
FROM jsdata JS 
WHERE JS.display=1 AND 1=1  
ORDER BY JS.submitday DESC LIMIT 2220,10;

--
# Query_time: 1.070827  Lock_time: 0.000065  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 2653
SELECT COUNT(id) AS sum FROM jsdata WHERE display=1;


Which MySQL version? Take read though use the index luke - all I think can be solved with additional indicies. jsdata_cat structure not shown - edit and include this.  Query 3 has no CAT table in query.

thank you, added version, and removed slow queries #3 & #4

My comment apparently got deleted, but in any case, I don't have a problem with 1 sec for query execution, given that most of your queries either involve every record or have joins.

hint: PRIMARY KEY (\id`)is a unique key, soUNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)` is not needed or helpful.

You have mariadb, not mysql. No, the two of these are not the same! Byw, you included the command line client's version, not the server's version...

The version seems to be MariaDB 5.5.56, an old, EOL version.

Use COUNT(*) instead of COUNT(id) for the second query.  The latter unnecessarily(?) checks each id for being NULL (which it cannot be).

Try adding a compound index to support your query's WHERE and ORDER BY clauses.  I think this one does the trick.
ALTER TABLE jsdata ADD INDEX ds(display, submitday);

Why will this help (if it does)? The index contains the field mentioned in your WHERE clause so the DBMS can find the  first eligible row. It then contains the rows presorted in the right order so the DBMS can skip the first 2210 of them then take the next ten without doing any actual sorting.
Notice that
SELECT lots, of, columns
      ... 
 ORDER BY something
 LIMIT bignumber, smallnumber

is a notorious query performance antipattern without index support. The DBMS must retrieve a lot of data, sort it, skip a lot of it, then  return just a few rows.
People in comments have noted that your DBMS software has been obsolete for years. I echo that note. Upgrade.

Note: "Rows_examined: 4883".  After adding OJones's index, that will probably drop to 10 (the LIMIT).  See Pagination and
